# Error when get json from Requests.get()

Tags: python, json, get, request

I used requests.get to get json from my webpage but I have recived some error when I run my code.
This is my code:

```
def get(t):
while 1:
    r = requests.get('http://raspberry.site11.com/controller.php')
    while r.status_code != 200:
        r = requests.get('http://raspberry.site11.com/controller.php')      
    d=r.json()
    dv1=d["Dv1"]
    dv2=d["Dv2"]
    dv3=d["Dv3"]
    dv4=d["Dv4"]    

    if dv1=="1":
        GPIO.output(6,0)
    else:
        GPIO.output(6,1)        
    if dv2=="1":
        GPIO.output(13,0)
    else:
        GPIO.output(13,1)           
    if dv3=="1":
        GPIO.output(19,0)
    else:
        GPIO.output(19,1)       
    if dv4=="1":
        GPIO.output(26,0)
    else:
        GPIO.output(26,1)   
    time.sleep(t)
```

And this is error I was recived:

```
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function get at 0xb6506930>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "thread.py", line 33, in get
    d=r.json()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 793, in json
    return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 4 - line 1 column 10 (char 3 - 9)
```

May everyone help me, thanks all so much.

Comment: Your endpoint is not returning JSON. But we can't help any more without seeing what it *does* return.

Comment: Seems to be working for me? Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that you're calling it in a while loop, and eventually you overload your server? Perhaps you should catch the error and log `r.content`. Also try checking your server logs when you catch the error. One final comment, your webpage is using the wrong content-type: `text/html`. It should be `application/json`

Comment: Thanks all so much. My problem was made by quality of Internet connection so I change to another host. ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do

```
def get_json(data):
    try:
        return data.json()
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Then

```
def get(t):
    while 1:
        r = requests.get('http://raspberry.site11.com/controller.php')
        while not get_json(r):
            r = requests.get('http://raspberry.site11.com/controller.php')      
        d = get_json(r)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My problem was made by quality of Internet connection so I change to another host. ^^